# Flutter: Best way to get all values in a form

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a data collection app which has multiple `TextField`s, like more than 12. I'm using a Form key to validate all of them. I want values of all the text fields so I can save them to firestore. How do I do this? Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainFormState createState() => _MainFormState();
}

class _MainFormState extends State<MainForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Enter information about PG Owner'),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                  onTap: () {},
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.face),
                      labelText: 'Enter Name of Owner',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.length < 15) {
                      return 'Address seems very short!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.room),
                      labelText: 'Enter full address of Owner',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.length < 9) {
                      return 'Phone number must be 9 digits or longer';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                      labelText: 'Phone number of Owner',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                    }
                    if (!value.contains('@')) {
                      return 'Email is invalid, must contain @';
                    }
                    if (!value.contains('.')) {
                      return 'Email is invalid, must contain .';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
                      labelText: 'Enter Email',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                ),
              ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Update: I know that proper way (I've read the docs) of getting values from a `TextField` is by creating a `controller`. But, In my case there are 14 `TextField`s which requires me to create 14 controllers. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There is also a known Flutter issue (proposal) being tracked at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107528.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using controller in TextFormField, you can get value of the TextFormField.

```
TextEditingController emailEditingController = TextEditingController();
TextFormField(
  controller: emailEditingController,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }
    if (!value.contains('@')) {
      return 'Email is invalid, must contain @';
    }
    if (!value.contains('.')) {
      return 'Email is invalid, must contain .';
    }
    return null;
  },
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
      labelText: 'Enter Email',
      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
);
```

Get Value like:

```
String email=emailEditingController.text;
```

**Updated Answer**

Get value by using onSubmitted

```
onSubmitted: (String value){email=value;},
```

Comment: I know about `TextEditingController`, my question is do I have to create a controller for every `TextField`? Since there are so many, I'm looking if there's a more convinient way.

Comment: @AmolBorkar you can use onSubmitted parameter in TextFormField.  Like: onSubmitted: (String value){email=value;},

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer: it does not show how to avoid creating a controller per form field: it is a code smell.

Answer (score 52):

You can use something like this in the following code:

***_formKey.currentState.save();*** calls the **onSaved()** on each textFormField items, which assigns the value to all the fields and you can use them as required. Try using the *_formKey.currentState.save();* just after *_formKey.currentState.validate()* is evaluated as true.

The form code looks like this:

```
String contactNumber;
String pin;
return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        onSaved: (String value){contactNumber=value;},
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
        maxLength: 10,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Enter Your Mobile Number",
            hintText: "Number",
            icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone)),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 10) {
            return 'Please Enter 10 digit number';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
      TextFormField(
        onSaved: (String value){pin=value;},
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
        maxLength: 10,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Enter Your PIN",
            hintText: "Number",
            icon: Icon(Icons.lock)),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 6) {
            return 'Please Enter 6 digit PIN';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.black,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                ***_formKey.currentState.save();***
                bloc.loginUser(contactNumber, pin);
              }
            },
            child: Text('Login' /*style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),*/)),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: This answer seems good, but what's a good way.. to create onsaved or have textEditingControllers

Answer (score 12):

I am not satisfied with how Flutter make you handle the form values yourself, you need to create a `TextEditingController` instance for each field, assign it to the `controller` and remember to dispose all of them manually. This leads to a lot of boilerplate code and makes it more error-prone:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final controller1 = TextEditingController();
final controller2 = TextEditingController();
final controller3 = TextEditingController();

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  controller1.dispose();
  controller2.dispose();
  controller3.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(children: [
      TextFormField(controller: controller1),
      TextFormField(controller: controller2),
      TextFormField(
        controller: controller3,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            final value1 = controller1.text;
            final value2 = controller2.text;
            final value3 = controller3.text;

            // do something with the form data
          }
        },
        child: const Text('Submit'),
      ),
    ]),
  );
}
```

A much less cumbersome way is to use the [`flutter_form_builder`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) package and replace `TextFormField` with the `FormBuilderTextField` widget which is a wrapper of the old plain `TextField`. You can see all of the supported input widgets [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder#input-widgets).

All you need to do now is to specify the name of each field in your form, and access it in `_formKey.currentState?.value`. See the example below:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FormBuilder(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(children: [
      FormBuilderTextField(name: 'field1'),
      FormBuilderTextField(name: 'field2'),
      FormBuilderTextField(
        name: 'field3',
        validator: FormBuilderValidators.required(
          context,
          errorText: 'Please enter some text',
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _formKey.currentState.save();
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            final formData = _formKey.currentState?.value;
            // formData = { 'field1': ..., 'field2': ..., 'field3': ... }
            // do something with the form data
          }
        },
        child: const Text('Submit'),
      ),
    ]),
  );
}
```

Comment: How to actually get the text from `field1`? I tried `print('$formData');` but to no avail.

Comment: tried this `print(formData);` it returns `I/flutter ( 4136): {}`

Answer (score 7):

I came here from a similar search. All the answers found did not satisfy my need, hence I wrote a custom solution.

- form key

```
    final _signUpKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

- declare your TextEditingController

```
    final Map<String, TextEditingController> sigUpController = {
      'firstName': TextEditingController(),
      'lastName': TextEditingController(),
      'email': TextEditingController(),
      'phone': TextEditingController(),
      'password': TextEditingController(),
    };
```

- Pass controller to TextFormField like this

```
    Form(
      key: _signUpKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: sigUpController['firstName'],
            validator: validator,
            autofocus: autofocus,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
            onTap: onTap,
            onChanged: onChanged,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                RegExp(r"[a-zA-Z]+|\s"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // define the other TextFormField here
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (!_signUpKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                return;
              }
    
              // To get data I wrote an extension method bellow
              final data = sigUpController.data();
    
              print('data: $data'); // data: {firstName: John, lastName: Doe, email: example@email.com, phone: 0000000000, password: password}
            },
            child: const Text('submit'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

- Extension method to get data from Map<String, TextEditingController>

```
    extension Data on Map<String, TextEditingController> {
      Map<String, dynamic> data() {
        final res = <String, dynamic>{};
        for (MapEntry e in entries) {
          res.putIfAbsent(e.key, () => e.value?.text);
        }
        return res;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [flutter_form_bloc](https://github.com/GiancarloCode/form_bloc/tree/master/packages/flutter_form_bloc), you don't need to create any `TextEditingController` and can separate the Business Logic from the User Interface, in addition to offering other advantages.

```
dependencies:
  flutter_bloc: ^0.21.0
  form_bloc: ^0.4.1
  flutter_form_bloc: ^0.3.0
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_bloc/flutter_form_bloc.dart';
import 'package:form_bloc/form_bloc.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MainForm()));

class MainFormBloc extends FormBloc<String, String> {
  final nameField = TextFieldBloc();
  final addressField = TextFieldBloc(validators: [
    (value) => value.length < 15 ? 'Address seems very short!' : null,
  ]);
  final phoneNumberField = TextFieldBloc(validators: [
    (value) =>
        value.length < 9 ? 'Phone number must be 9 digits or longer' : null,
  ]);
  final emailField = TextFieldBloc(validators: [Validators.email]);

  @override
  List<FieldBloc> get fieldBlocs => [
        nameField,
        addressField,
        phoneNumberField,
        emailField,
      ];

  @override
  Stream<FormBlocState<String, String>> onSubmitting() async* {
    // This method is called when you call [mainFormBloc.submit]
    // and each field bloc have a valid value.
    // And you can save them in firestore.
    print(nameField.value);
    print(addressField.value);
    print(phoneNumberField.value);
    print(emailField.value);

    yield currentState.toSuccess('Data saved successfully.');

    // yield `currentState.toLoaded()` because
    // you can't submit if the state is `FormBlocSuccess`.
    // In most cases you don't need to do this,
    // because you only want to submit only once.
    yield currentState.toLoaded();
  }
}

class MainForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<MainFormBloc>(
      builder: (context) => MainFormBloc(),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final formBloc = BlocProvider.of<MainFormBloc>(context);

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Main Form')),
            body: FormBlocListener<MainFormBloc, String, String>(
              onSuccess: (context, state) {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(
                    content: Text(state.successResponse),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                );
              },
              onSubmissionFailed: (context, state) {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Some fields have invalid data.'),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                    textFieldBloc: formBloc.nameField,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    autofocus: true,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.face),
                        labelText: 'Enter Name of Owner',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                  TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                    textFieldBloc: formBloc.addressField,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.room),
                        labelText: 'Enter full address of Owner',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                  TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                    textFieldBloc: formBloc.phoneNumberField,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                        labelText: 'Phone number of Owner',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                  TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                    textFieldBloc: formBloc.emailField,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
                        labelText: 'Enter Email',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: formBloc.submit,
                      child: Center(child: Text('SUBMIT')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this flutter package [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder), it will help you from repeating yourself by creating multiple controllers for each form field. In addition to that, it will help you in validating the form, and updating the form with simplicity by using only a simple form key to control the entire form.

Answer (score -1):

I can see alot of accurate answers. but dont forget to trim your text. .trim() helps you remove trailing and leading spaces.

```
_cityController.text.trim();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35845982)