# How to access dynamic input fields values on button click in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am working on an attendance application where I assign wages to the workers. I want to store all the wages given to the workers into the database. But the problem is I want to access all the given values on button click. I have no idea how it can be done in flutter. I am a beginner.

I have given all the codes and the image of what output i want.

**Image of Emulator**
[image]

Here is my code...

***ATTENDANCE SCREEN***

```
...rest code...
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Upload Patti'),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListBody(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _mainWagesController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: "Enter Amount",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.wallet, color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      newWages = _mainWagesController.text;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: const Text("Assign Wages"),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.check_circle),
      ),
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.00),
          child: Column(children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                "Date :  ${DateFormat.yMMMEd().format(DateTime.parse(widget.attendanceDate.toString()))}",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: SupervisorAttendanceServices.getAttendancesDetailsList(
                  widget.attendanceId),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var data = snapshot.data['hamal'];
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return HamalAttendanceWidget(
                            workerId: data[index]['worker_id'],
                            name: data[index]['worker_name'],
                            wages: newWages,
                            masterAttendanceId: widget.attendanceId,
                            isPrensent: data[index]
                                    ['attendance_worker_presense']
                                .toString());
                      });
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text("Something went wrong !"),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
...rest code
```

***widget***

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(children: [
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              width: 10,
              height: 50,
            ),
            const Icon(FeatherIcons.user),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Text(
              widget.name,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                width: 150,
                height: 60,
                child: TextFormField(
                  // onChanged: _onChangeHandler,
                  initialValue: widget.wages.toString(),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Wages",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.wallet,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      )),
                )),
          ],
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you have multiple textfield, you need to have an array of controllers. By Looping through the array you can get their specific text. `textController.text`

Comment: Please provide me some code snippet sir

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a StateManager for your application, for example [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get)
is a good solution. Create a controller file like the below:

```
// define this enum outside of class to handle the state of the page for load data 

enum AppState { initial, loading, loaded, error, empty, disabled }
Rx<AppState> pageState = AppState.initial.obs;

class AttendanceCntroller extends GetxController{
RxList<dynamic> dataList=RxList<dynamic>();
   @override
     void onInit() {
     //you can write other codes in here to handle data
     pageState(AppState.loading);

     dataList.value=
     SupervisorAttendanceServices.getAttendancesDetailsList(attendanceId);

     pageState(AppState.loaded);

     super.onInit();
   }
}
```

and in your view(UI) page, handle it in this way:

```
class AttendanceView extends GetView<AttendanceCntroller>{
  @override
   Widget body(BuildContext context) {
   // TODO: implement body
   return Obx( ()=> controller.pageState.value==AppState.loading ? const
   Center(child: LinearProgressIndicator()) :  ListView.builder(
    itemCount: controller.dataList.length,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return HamalAttendanceWidget(
          workerId: controller.dataList['worker_id'],
          name: controller.dataList['worker_name'],
          wages: newWages,
          masterAttendanceId: widget.attendanceId,
          isPrensent: controller.dataList[index]
          ['attendance_worker_presense']
              .toString());
    })
)
```

}
}

for more data read the GetX link and read clean architecture with the GetX sample repository of my [GitHub](https://github.com/M4RZB4Ni/Flutter-Clean-Architecture) it have advanced management of states with GetX with dependency injection handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have prefilled value in `TextFormField`, you can either use `initialValue` or `controller` parameter.

The value of `controller` parameter will help you to get/update the value of `TextFormField`.

For controller parameter refer below.

```
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: 'This is text will be pre-filled in TextFormField');
...
TextFormField(
  controller: controller,
);
```

Create List or Map of those controllers.

```
List<TextEditingController> listOfControllers = [ controller1, controlle2,...];
```

Use for loop through this List on onClick() method of Button.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    for(var controllerItem in listOfControllers) {
      print(controllerItem.text); // the value of TextFormField
    }
  },
)
```