# How to compare value within 2 TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I wish to validate if the values within 2 `TextFormField`s matches.

I could validate them individually.

But how could I capture both those values to validate by comparing?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegisterForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterFormState createState() => _RegisterFormState();
}

class _RegisterFormState extends State<RegisterForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            height: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Password'
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      // I want to compare this value against the TextFormField below.
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return 'is empty';
                      }
                      return value;
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Confirm Password'
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return 'is empty';
                      }
                      return value;
                    },
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        print('ok');
                      } else {
                        print('not ok');
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

One possible solution as follows.

I could store them as values within `_RegisterFormState` and retrieve them within the `validate` blocks. But is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

```
class _RegisterFormState extends State<RegisterForm> {

    
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    String password;
    String confirmPassword;

.....

    TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Password'
        ),
        validator: (value) {
            // I want to compare this value against the TextFormField below.
            if(value.isEmpty){
                setState(() {
                    password = value;
                });
                performValidation(password, confirmPassword); // some custom validation method 
                return 'is empty';
            }
            return value;
        },
    ),

    ..... 
}
```

P.S: If there would be a better way to do it via a state management tool, I am using `Provider`. Not looking for Bloc solutions.

Comment: You can use TextEditingController. Declare TextEditingController in your widget and than assign to property controller of password TextFormField and than in confirm password just check value from your passwordController if they are same.

Comment: @savke Thanks. Its a valid solution, but I'd stick with the above solution if that is the only other alternative. Not in this case but if for some reason I need to use 3 fields or more, that would mean additional Controller for at least 2 of em.

Comment: than what type of solution you are searching for? Something like dynamic way to validate?

Comment: Yes. not looking to have to concern with the number of text fields I am working with which is used to perform different operations. I am expecting a couple of upcoming features which would benefit from some dynamic setup. And while at it trying to see if I could stick with a a stateless widget, maybe by using Provider. Question is whether this is possible.

Comment: I don't think it's smart using Provider in managing form state. Can you describe how do you think that will work, maybe we can find some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few steps I have performed to achieve this. You can refer that to achieve your goal.

1. Create a stateful widget and return a InputBox from there
2. add a property named as callback and set it's datatype as

   ValueSetter callback;
3. assign this callback to onChanged Event of the input box

> onChanged: (text) {
> widget.callback(text);
> },

- Use your custom widget in the class where you want to use the input box
- while using your widget pass a callback to it

  ```
              InputWithLabel(

                 callback: (value) {

                     password = value;

                   },
               ),
               InputWithLabel(

                 callback: (value) {

                       confirmPassword = value;

                 },
               ),
  ```
- and at last, we have to compare those values,
  you can bind a key to your form add use it in **saved** event of it. You can wrap it in Button's callback

  ```
  if (InputValidation.validatePasswordandConfirm(password, cpassword)) {
  // your after form code
  }
  ```

To have it a real time comparison mark one of the input's callback in setState(){} and create a new property in your Custom Text Widget named as compareTxt;

and on validator check for compare text and return the error message

```
validator: (text) {
          if (widget.comaparetext != text) {
            return 'Password does not match';
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I was using custom TextFormField widgets.
So this is how I achieved it:

Problem:
I had two TextFormField widgets in a Form and I wanted to compare the values
of those two TextFormWidgets, to check whether the value of one filed is greater
then the other.

Solution:
I defined two controllers globally, because the TextFormWidgets were in a separate class.

```
final _startingRollNumberController = TextEditingController();
final _endingRollNumberController = TextEditingController();
```

Passed these controllers to the instances of TextFormField in the Form class.

```
CustomTextField('Starting R#', _startingRollNumberController),
CustomTextField('Ending R#', _endingRollNumberController),
```

And validated them in the TextFormField class.

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  // *===== CustomTextField class =====* //
  CustomTextField(this._hintText, this._controller);

  final String _hintText;
  final _controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      validator: (value) {
        final _startingRollNumber = _startingRollNumberController.text;
        final _endingRollNumber = _endingRollNumberController.text;
        // Starting roll-number needs to be smaller then the ending roll-number.
        if (!_startingRollNumber.isEmpty && !_endingRollNumber.isEmpty) {
          if (int.parse(_startingRollNumber) >= int.parse(_endingRollNumber)) {
            return 'starting roll number must be smaller.';
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This may not be the best approach but this is how I achieved it. There is
also, this [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) package which can be used to achieve this easily using the form key.
A related question: [Flutter: Best way to get all values in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117205/flutter-best-way-to-get-all-values-in-a-form)